# Hard-coded resource path vs $Resource global variable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources

I've never been able to work out which format is better or if there any differences between these lightning resource access formats:

```
<img src="{!$Resource.your_pic}"/>
```

And

```
<img src="/resource/your_pic"/>
```

Most of the time the documentation recommends the former format, but the latter is sometimes used, seems to work fine and looks a lot cleaner.

Can anyone shed some illumination on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$Resource` has two benefits: cache busting and automatic path resolution. By cache busting, we're referring to the fact that the `/resource/name` has a very long expiry time, and so you'll find it harder to load changes to the file without clearing your browser's cache. `$Resource` solves this by putting a timestamp from the resource into the url, something like `/resource/123893218321/name`. This allows the long expiry to work for each version of the file.

By automatic path resolution, we're primarily concerned about communities and portals. These can have prefixes, which ultimately alter the path you need to use. For example, in a community, it might be `/s/resource/name` instead of just `/resource/name`, so the user would get a 404 (e.g. a blank image, error message, something else). As a further benefit, if salesforce.com decides to alter how these files are accessed, developers that have been using $Resource will already be prepared for those changes, while those using `/resource/` may have to update their code.

This $Resource variable, by the way, works in both Lightning and Visualforce, and should always be used. Some documentation may choose not to do this, but it definitely should not be considered a best practice.

Comment: Nicely put. Looks like I'll be using the Global var next time :)